# Why is the closed unit ball $B(0,1)$ is not compact under the discrete metric?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The distance is given by
$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} &0, \qquad x=y \\ &1, \qquad x\neq y \end{cases}.$$
I am trying to prove that the closed unit ball $B(0,1) = \{x : d(0,x)\le 1 \}$ is not compact. To prove this, I considered to establish an open cover which has no finite subcover. But I can't.
How do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the only compact are finite sets. For example, let take the covering $\{\{x\}\}_{x\in B(0,1)}$ can you find a finite sub-covering  of $B(0,1)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

You did not say on what set the metric $d$ is defined. I will take  it to be an arbitrary non-empty set.

I suppose $0$ refers to some fixed point of the metric space.The closed ball of radius $1$ around  this point is the entire space $X$. This is compact iff $X$ is a finite set because singleton  sets form an open cover of the space.